# Android, Writing an app that takes a picture and then sends that picture in a post request

Tags: android

I've gotten far enough that I can seemingly activate the camera and get the intent picture back, however the post request part seems to be a much larger issue. After constantly running into "NetworkOnMainThreadException"s and context errors, I sort of combined some things that I learned here into something...that still doesn't get rid of that exception. I'm sure that there are issues elsewhere too.

Edit: Here's the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE =1;
//final IntentServiceActivity intentPost = new IntentServiceActivity();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button captureButton = findViewById(R.id.CaptureButton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });

}
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
protected  void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        IntentServiceActivity intentPost = new IntentServiceActivity();
        intentPost.postRequest(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Then:

```
public class IntentServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
public void postRequest(Bitmap bmp){
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.14:8000/trash/");

    try {
        File f = new File(myApp.getAppContext().getFilesDir(), "temp");
        f.createNewFile();

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(f));

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        Log.d("response", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        result.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        Log.d("Debug", "the end!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
public class myApp extends Application {
private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myApp.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return myApp.context;
}
```

}

I have added the uses-feature for camera and the uses-permission for internet as well as a name, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: Use AsyncTask to execute network in background thread. You can use Reftrofit kind of  library and it contain method to execute network in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you try to execute a network a request on main UI thread. Such behavior makes application unresponsive. In order to handle such scenarios, you should always use a separate thread for network and heavy processing code logics. `AsyncTask` is one of the best ways to create a separate thread for heavy work.

Below is working code according to your request. Just change your `IntentServiceActivity` as follows

```
public class IntentServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView result;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void postRequest(Bitmap bmp) {
        this.bitmap = bmp;
        new UploadImageTask().execute();
    }


    private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(IntentServiceActivity.this, "Uploading Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.14:8000/trash/");

                File f = new File(myApp.getAppContext().getFilesDir(), "temp");
                f.createNewFile();

                //Convert bitmap to byte array
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                //write the bytes in file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(bitmapdata);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(f));

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                String responseTxt = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                return responseTxt;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultTxt) {
            super.onPostExecute(resultTxt);
            Toast.makeText(IntentServiceActivity.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("response", resultTxt);
            if(result !== null) result.setText(resultTxt);
            Log.d("Debug", "the end!");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! While other answers were proven to be correct in general, I chose this one because it was the neatest to me; thanks to the use of the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkOnMainThreadException this exception is thrown when your  application perform a networking operation(service call) on its main thread.

Use **AsyncTask ** for avoid this exception.

```
class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       //here you can show progress dialog
    }

protected void doInBackground(String... data) {
    try {

         postRequest(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(void res) {

}
}
```

Then Change in IntentServiceActivity  class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
UploadImageTask task= new UploadImageTask ();
  task.execute();
```

}

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception suggests, you are not allowed to trigger network calls on the main thread in Android. What you need to use is an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers

I really suggest you work through a few Android tutorials before starting developing Android apps because not every standard Java pattern is applicable in Android. I recommend [this](https://eu.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851) course because it is free and it teaches you the standard Android design patterns. It is also thaught by Google employees so I can assure you they know what they are talking about.